# How do I use NuGet (or something else) to sync local projects with eachother?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, nuget

I have three Visual Studio (2013) projects, not necessarily in the same solution. LibA, LibB and App. I have both C# code and TypeScript in the LibA and LibB. App should be able to use all the code in LibA and LibB, just like I normally would be referencing C# code in a DLL into my project with "Add Reference".

So if I make a change (C# or Typescript) in LibA and build the project, then change should directly be available in App. TypeScript dependencies should also be resolved by this.

Example TypeScript code in App project:

```
module App
{
    export function init()
    {
       LibA.anyMethod();
       LibB.anyMethod2();
    }
}
```

I want a very simple solution. I don't work with other developers in a team so that doesn't have to be taken into account.

Comment: What structures have you tried? As asked, this is too broad. There are many ways to do it, all of them workable. Further, You'd probably share a .NET assembly as a binary, whereas you might share typescript instead as a definition file with the complied JS. It's up to you.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I currently share assemblies as binaries between the projects. But that only covers the C# code. I'm looking for a simple automated solution that syncs both the C# and the TypeScript at once. I understand NuGet can solve that somehow, but haven't found a good resource that I can use.

Comment: What do you mean, "syncs the C#"? As source code, or binaries? A `robocopy` as part of a build script would work in both cases.

Comment: Well, syncs might be a bad choice of word. The C# code would ofcourse be made available through a project reference, but the TypeScript wouldn't. So I'm after a simple method to make all my code available with one method. I understand that' the point with NuGet. But I would need to make it work locally between project. But that might be hard since I didn't find any clear turorials on the matter. I'll consider a proj reference combined with a robocopy script. Thanx.